# How to get cumulative counts for each ID at that point in time based on entries in another column ina a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, cumulative-sum

I have a dataframe as shown below:

| CLIENT_ID | ENCOUNTER_DATE | CONDITION |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8222 | 2020-01-01 | Positive |
| 8222 | 2020-03-02 | Treated |
| 8222 | 2020-04-18 | Treated |
| 8222 | 2020-07-31 | Negative |
| 8300 | 2017-06-10 | Negative |
| 8300 | 2017-09-11 | Treated |
| 8300 | 2018-02-01 | Future Treatment |
| 8300 | 2018-04-01 | Treated |
| 8300 | 2018-05-31 | Negative |
| 8400 | 2020-12-31 | Future Treatment |
| 8401 | 2017-08-29 | Negative |
| 8401 | 2017-09-15 | Positive |
| 8500 | 2018-10-10 | Positive |

Here is the code to create df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"CLIENT_ID": [8222, 8222, 8222, 8222, 8300, 8300, 8300, 8300, 8300, 8400, 8401, 8401, 8500],
                   "ENCOUNTER_DATE": ['2020-01-01', '2020-03-02', '2020-04-18', '2020-07-31', '2017-06-10', '2017-09-11', '2018-02-01', '2018-04-01', '2018-05-31', '2020-12-31', '2017-08-29', '2017-09-15', '2018-10-10'],
                   "CONDITION": ["positive", "treated", "treated", "negative", "negative", "treated", "future treatment", "treated", "negative", "future treatment", "negative", "positive", "positive"]})

manage_condition_list = ['positive','treated','future treatment']
```

The table is sorted by the `CLIENT_ID` and `DATE_ENCOUNTER`.

I want to get the cumulative count (number of times) that client, `CLIENT_ID` had a `CONDITION` in the list `manage_condition_list` at that point in time. So that final dataframe or output will look like below:

| CLIENT_ID | ENCOUNTER_DATE | CONDITION | CONDITION_COUNTS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8222 | 2020-01-01 | Positive | 1 |
| 8222 | 2020-03-02 | Treated | 2 |
| 8222 | 2020-04-18 | Treated | 3 |
| 8222 | 2020-07-31 | Negative | 3 |
| 8300 | 2017-06-10 | Negative | 0 |
| 8300 | 2017-09-11 | Treated | 1 |
| 8300 | 2018-02-01 | Future Treatment | 2 |
| 8300 | 2018-04-01 | Treated | 3 |
| 8300 | 2018-05-31 | Negative | 3 |
| 8400 | 2020-12-31 | Future Treatment | 1 |
| 8401 | 2017-08-29 | Negative | 0 |
| 8401 | 2017-09-15 | Positive | 1 |
| 8500 | 2018-10-10 | Positive | 1 |

Note the real data has significantly more entries NOT in the `manage_condition_list`. I am thinking a combination of `df.where` and `cumcount() + 1` but am not too sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `isin` to get True if the value is in the list `manage_condition_list` on the column CONDITION, then `groupby.cumsum` by the CLIENT_ID column

```
df['CONDITION_COUNTS'] = (
    df['CONDITION'].isin(manage_condition_list)
      .groupby(df['CLIENT_ID']).cumsum()
)
print(df)
    CLIENT_ID ENCOUNTER_DATE         CONDITION  CONDITION_COUNTS
0        8222     2020-01-01          positive                 1
1        8222     2020-03-02           treated                 2
2        8222     2020-04-18           treated                 3
3        8222     2020-07-31          negative                 3
4        8300     2017-06-10          negative                 0
5        8300     2017-09-11           treated                 1
6        8300     2018-02-01  future treatment                 2
7        8300     2018-04-01           treated                 3
8        8300     2018-05-31          negative                 3
9        8400     2020-12-31  future treatment                 1
10       8401     2017-08-29          negative                 0
11       8401     2017-09-15          positive                 1
12       8500     2018-10-10          positive                 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether I understood the logic behind cum_counts, but hope this helps

```
df['Cum_Count']= df.groupby('CLIENT_ID').cumcount('Condition')
df
```

or

```
df['Cum_Count']= df.groupby('CLIENT_ID')['CONDITION'].cumcount()
```

or

```
df['CONDITION_COUNTS'] = (df['CONDITION'].isin(manage_condition_list).groupby(df['CLIENT_ID']).cumcount())
```

Comment: does not consider values in aforementioned list

Comment: df['CONDITION_COUNTS'] = (df['CONDITION'].isin(manage_condition_list).groupby(df['CLIENT_ID']).cumcount())
df['CONDITION_COUNTS']